# More than 3-Way Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, checkbox

I want to implement an country-selection-input. In other words, I've got a form with a 25x25px flag, which I want to be clickable - say, german as default, first click changes it to netherlands, second to swiss or w/e.

The last chosen value needs to be in my POST-Array with the other values of the form.

I've tried to accomplish this using 3-Way checkboxes with javascript, but I'm going to need more than 3 options.

Any idea on how to do this? I've thought about an input select, hiding everything but the current value - but I don't know how to submit this to change to the next value.

Thanks in advance for any input, and please don't judge me for such a question - this is my first js/html/css project. :-)

Comment: drop down menu​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: a `button` whose value changes on click?

Comment: hidden `input` to hold a value and `img` to represent a flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
    <img src="german.png" onclick="switchCountry(this);"/>
    <input id="country" name="country" type="hidden" value="german" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var countries = ['german', 'netherlands', 'swiss'];

var switchCountry = function(img) {
    var input = document.getElementById('country'),
        oldValue = input.getAttribute('value'),
        newValue = countries[(countries.indexOf(oldValue) + 1) % countries.length];

    // Switch input value that will be posted with form 
    input.setAttribute('value', newValue);

    // Switch graphical representation of country
    img.setAttribute('src', newValue + '.png');
};
```

Example here http://jsbin.com/alasip/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll vote you up as soon as I get the reputation.

Comment: @PadvonDo You already have enough reputation to accept the answer which was the most helpful. See the last paragraph here http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts

Comment: Just did that, thank you. Guess I need to get into this site some more.